# How to use Picasso Library with MediaStore

Tags: android, picasso

I want to get uri of stored images of gallery using MediaStore.Images.Media and load images using Picasso library. I have done this using below code. But it neither gives any error nor display images in imageview (which is present in listview).

```
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                .resize(300, 300).centerInside().into(holder.imageView);
```

Anybody help me please....

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually query the database for the images uri in the MediaStore.

For example to get the first image from the MediaStore and load it you would do

```
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
        };
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        mCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
        if (mCursor != null) {
            columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

            int size = mCursor.getCount();
            // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
            if (size == 0) {
                return;
            }

            mCursor.moveToPosition(0);
            int imageID = mCursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageID));

           Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUri)
            .resize(300, 300).centerInside().into(holder.imageView);
        }
```

Also because this is a DB query, you should possibly do this in a AsyncTask, and return the URI to postExecute and load it in Picasso since DB reads can be slow on some devices.

Comment: I already did this exactly. The problem is that app takes time to extract Uri of all the images of mediastore even though i used Asynctask for uri processing. Thats why i need to simplify that process. Thanks alot for putting ur effort and time in solving my problem.

Comment: Yea, Database reads/writes are expensive and should always be done in a background thread/AsyncTask, so you should load a Progress Spinner that shows the page is doing something to the user while the data is being processed. If you need more of a "Immediate" visible screen, then you can do this heavy lifting at Application launch time in the onCreate of an Application extended class, and store the  Uri's in Memory until you need them.